# to create customized website in Microsoft what tools do we need as an developer to build it ?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, analysis, developer-tools

I am BA and want to know what things a developer needs to have to build a website in Microsoft (it will be fully customized / partially customized online service selling a website, have price calculator based on N no. of various option user select and lot of other things around it and the admin panel to change rate, tax, etc. in it)

The website will have automated email, payment, forms, reporting, role & access, a different type of end users & a lot of calculation logic as well.

I am listing the thing we need to install as i can find the cost (especially hidden cost to develop a website).

I am representing Non-IT company (not in India), then do we need to buy the licence for all the Microsoft tools developer needs? If yes please mention tools we need to buy a licence for along with the tools list

Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: That`s kind of billing topic - not development, and question is too broad as well and answer very opinion based. Like build me a spaceship ....

Comment: billing is something I can look into, but tools used  to build a fully functional responsive website in Microsoft is the answer I am expecting, as I am not sure what tools they will be using for developing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, but for the functionality that you are describing, here is a very basic web development setup:

- Windows server to host the website (x2 for dev)
- Database server and software (SQL goes well with .net) (x2 for dev)
- Microsoft Visual Studio to install on a desktop device to build the actual website, assuming you are building in C#.NET or VB.NET

Of course, your second paragraph lists additional functionality that may require more hardware, software, and integrations(email servers, payment systems, etc.) depending on what you have or don't have.

All of this can be hosted in a cloud platform like azure, aws, or it can be done internally